# HTML check values of two radio buttons with js

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I have two radio buttons in my HTML. At least one of them has to be at value "yes". I would like to check values when user clics on the second one (if it is "yes", then we don't care, if it is "no", then we have to check what is the value of first one). I tried with this JavaScript code, but it doesn't work. 
Can somebody help me with this? Thank you.

```
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label class="form-text">Show email.</label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-8">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-secondary active">
                <input type="radio" name="email" id="yes" value="yes" autocomplete="off" checked="checked"> Yes
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-secondary">
                <input type="radio" name="email" id="no" value="no" autocomplete="off"> No
            </label>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label class="form-text">Show number.</label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-8">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-secondary active">
                <input type="radio" name="number" id="yes" value="yes" autocomplete="off" checked="checked"> Yes
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-secondary">
                <input type="radio" name="number" id="no" value="no" autocomplete="off" onclick="check(this)"> No
            </label>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

        <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
            function check(input) {
                if (document.getElementById('email').value == "no" && document.getElementById('number').value == "no") 
                {
                    input.setCustomValidity('One must be yes.');
                } else {
                    // input is valid -- reset the error message
                    input.setCustomValidity('');
                        }
                }
        </script>
```

Comment: You are repeating ids (yes and no).  That's invalid by web standards.

Comment: Also you are trying to find the radio's by id, but they do not have an id on them matching their name.  You should put a common class on them, and find the selected one.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this might work:

```
        <label class="btn btn-secondary active">
            <input type="radio" name="email" id="firstRadioTrue" value="yes" autocomplete="off" checked="checked"> Yes
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-secondary">
            <input type="radio" name="email" id="firstRadioFalse" value="no" autocomplete="off"> No
        </label> 
        <label class="btn btn-secondary active">
            <input type="radio" name="number" id="secondRadioTrue" value="yes" autocomplete="off" checked="checked"> Yes
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-secondary">
            <input type="radio" name="number" id="secondRadioFalse" value="no" autocomplete="off"> No
        </label>



        <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>

        var radioTopOne = document.getElementById('firstRadioTrue');
        var radioTopTwo = document.getElementById('firstRadioFalse');

        var radioOne = document.getElementById('secondRadioTrue');
        var radioTwo = document.getElementById('secondRadioFalse');

        radioOne.addEventListener('click',function(){
            if(radioOne.checked == true && radioTopOne.checked == true){
                alert("BOTH TRUE");
            }
            else if(radioOne.checked == true && radioTopOne.checked == false){
                alert("TOP FALSE, BOT TRUE");
            };
        });
        radioTwo.addEventListener('click',function(){
            if(radioTwo.checked == true && radioTopTwo.checked == true){
                alert("BOTH FALSE");
            }
            else if(radioTwo.checked == true && radioTopTwo.checked == false){
                alert("BOT FALSE, TOP TRUE");
            }
        });




    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you have no element with the `id` "email", nor any element with the `id` "number". You should give the two radio buttons you are using in your `if` statement an `id` with which you can check if they are checked (`HTMLInputElement.checked`). The value of the `input` will always be the same even if they aren't checked.

```html
 <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label class="form-text">Show email.</label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-8">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-secondary active">
                <input type="radio" name="email" id="showemailyes" value="yes" autocomplete="off" checked="checked"> Yes
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-secondary">
                <input type="radio" name="email" id="showemailno" value="no" autocomplete="off"> No
            </label>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label class="form-text">Show number.</label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-8">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-secondary active">
                <input type="radio" name="number" id="shownumberyes" value="yes" autocomplete="off" checked="checked"> Yes
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-secondary">
                <input type="radio" name="number" id="shownumberno" value="no" autocomplete="off" onclick="check(this)"> No
            </label>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

        <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
            function check(input) {
                if (document.getElementById('showemailno').checked && document.getElementById('shownumberno').checked) 
                {
                   alert("One must be yes.");
                    input.setCustomValidity('One must be yes.');
                } else {
                    // input is valid -- reset the error message
                    input.setCustomValidity('');
                        }
                }
        </script>
```